# How to get rid of error running tests? Class SomeClass is implemented in both path1 and path2 One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, uitest

I have been battling really hard to get rid of this problem. It just started happening on Xcode9.

When ever I run unit test (Command + U) - I get the following out put. It's always after the unit tests have completed and before the UI Tests will begin running.

I have tried to look at the problem on GitHub - this seem to be related to cocoa pods, but I don't have any pods installed on my project. I am using Carthage and have followed all the recommended steps to properly add frameworks.

If it's not harmful, is there a way to silence this warning. I would like to resolve the issue, because I don't want this to become a critical problem later down the line.

Thank you,

```
Running tests...
    objc[42045]: Class ___MKPlaceBusinessInfoItemAccessibility_super is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb66f00) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6e7b0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class _MKPlaceBusinessInfoItemAccessibility is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb66f28) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6e7d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class __MKTransitInfoLabelViewAccessibility_super is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb66fa0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6e850). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class MKTransitInfoLabelViewAccessibility is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb66fc8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6e878). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class __MKPlaceViewNearbyAppsCellAccessibility_super is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb67040) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6e8f0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class MKPlaceViewNearbyAppsCellAccessibility is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb67068) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6e918). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class __MKPlaceCardHeaderViewControllerAccessibility_super is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb670e0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6e990). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class MKPlaceCardHeaderViewControllerAccessibility is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb67108) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6e9b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class ___MKMapContentViewAccessibility_super is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb67180) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6ea30). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class _MKMapContentViewAccessibility is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb671a8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6ea58). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class ___MKPlaceInlineMapContentViewAccessibility_super is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb67220) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6ead0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class _MKPlaceInlineMapContentViewAccessibility is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb67248) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6eaf8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class __MKPlaceInfoURLRowViewAccessibility_super is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb672c0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6eb70). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class MKPlaceInfoURLRowViewAccessibility is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb672e8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6eb98). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class __MKPlaceCardActionSectionViewAccessibility_super is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb67360) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6ec10). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class MKPlaceCardActionSectionViewAccessibility is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb67388) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6ec38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class __MKPlacePhotosViewControllerAccessibility_super is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb67400) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6ecb0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class MKPlacePhotosViewControllerAccessibility is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb67428) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6ecd8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class __MKCompassViewAccessibility_super is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb674a0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6ed50). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class MKCompassViewAccessibility is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb674c8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6ed78). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[42045]: Class ___MKLineHeaderModelAccessibility_super is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKit.axbundle/MapKit (0x11fb67540) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit (0x11fe6eee0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Comment: Please review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+is+implemented+in+both+One+of+the+two+will+be+used.+Which+one+is+undefined.) on the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [100+ "Class implemented in both MapKit and VectorKit" warnings with Xcode 9.0.1 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852386/100-class-implemented-in-both-mapkit-and-vectorkit-warnings-with-xcode-9-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

the TL:DR is you are running into an apple radar: http://www.openradar.me/34871338

Here is the issue you are duplicating: [100+ "Class implemented in both MapKit and VectorKit" warnings with Xcode 9.0.1 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852386/100-class-implemented-in-both-mapkit-and-vectorkit-warnings-with-xcode-9-0-1)